# AVCaptureSession audio doesn't work for long videos

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I'm using AVCaptureSession to record a video with audio. Everything seems to work properly for short videos, but for some reason, if I record a video that is longer than about 12 seconds, the audio doesn't work.

Comment: it's actually more then 10secs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We also experienced this issue. Basically disabling movie fragment writing will work but it doesn't actually explain the issue. Most likely you are recording to an output file using a file extension that does not support this feature, like `mp4`. If you pass an output file with the extension `mov` you should have no issues using movie fragment writing and the output file will have audio.

Answer (score 34):

**Edit** (*because this answer is still getting upvotes*): This answer works to mitigate the problem but the likely root cause for the issue is addressed in [@jfeldman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666844/2226732).

---

I found the solution as [an answer to a completely different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543180/weird-bug-with-avcapturesession#answer-25997260).

The issue is the `movieFragmentInterval` property in AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.

The documentation for this property explains what these fragments are:

> A QuickTime movie is comprised of media samples and a sample table
> identifying their location in the file. A movie file without a sample
> table is unreadable.
>
> In a processed file, the sample table typically appears at the
> beginning of the file. It may also appear at the end of the file, in
> which case the header contains a pointer to the sample table at the
> end. When a new movie file is being recorded, it is not possible to
> write the sample table since the size of the file is not yet known.
> Instead, the table is must be written when recording is complete. If
> no other action is taken, this means that if the recording does not
> complete successfully (for example, in the event of a crash), the file
> data is unusable (because there is no sample table). By periodically
> inserting “movie fragments” into the movie file, the sample table can
> be built up incrementally. This means that if the file is not written
> completely, the movie file is still usable (up to the point where the
> last fragment was written).

It also says:

> The default is 10 seconds. Set to kCMTimeInvalid to disable movie
> fragment writing (not typically recommended).

So for some reason my recording is getting messed up whenever a fragment is written. I just added the line `movieFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid;` (where `movieFileOutput` is the AVCaptureMovieFileOutput I've added to the AVCaptureSession) to disable fragment writing, and the audio now works.

Answer (score 5):

Updating `videoFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid` solved this for me.

However, I accidentally set the `movieFragmentInterval` after calling `startRecordingToOutputFileURL`. An agonizing hour later I realized my mistake. For newbies like me, *note this obvious sequence*.

```
videoFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
videoFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
```

Answer (score 4):

kCMTimeInvalid is now deprecated. This is how to assign it now:

`videoFileOutput?.movieFragmentInterval = CMTime.invalid`