# Audio Not Recording in AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have an app that when a view is loaded up, begins capturing video and audio, and upon completion, records it to both the documents folder of the app, along with the Camera Roll of the iPad that it is running on.  I have made sure and added in the input to the session for both audio and video, but when I go to view the saved video, there is no audio with it.  Can anyone spot anything in my code that would point out where the problem is?

UPDATE: No error messages ever show. However, I found a common denominator. Audio will record, but only if recording is 10 seconds or shorter. If it hits 11 seconds the audio doesn't record.

NSLog shows

> Finished with error: (null)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d hh:mm:ss a"];
    // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSError* error4 = nil;
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error4];
    OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
    UInt32 allowMixing = true;
    propertySetError |= AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);

    // Activate the audio session
    error4 = nil;
    if (![audioSession setActive:YES error:&error4]) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setActive:YES failed: %@", [error4 localizedDescription]);
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [session beginConfiguration];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSError *error2 = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error2];


    AVCaptureDevice *device;
    AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    // find the front facing camera

    device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


    // get the input device
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];




    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    NSString *archives = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"archives"];
    NSString *editedfilename = [[@"ComeOnDown" lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString *datestring = [[editedfilename stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:currentTime];
    NSLog(@"%@", datestring);
    NSString *outputpathofmovie = [[archives stringByAppendingPathComponent:datestring] stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputpathofmovie];
    [session addInput:audioInput];
    [session addInput:deviceInput];
    [session addOutput:movieFileOutput];
    [session commitConfiguration];
    [session startRunning];




    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    previewLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;

     CALayer *rootLayer = [vImagePreview layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [previewLayer setFrame:[rootLayer bounds]];
    [rootLayer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    [movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];



    //session = nil;
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed with error %d", (int)[error code]]
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

    }
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

}

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections {

}
-(void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
    NSLog(@"Finished with error: %@", error);
}
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {
    //finished
    NSLog(@"Finished");
    NSString *proud = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[outputFileURL path]];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(proud, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), (__bridge void *)(proud));
}
```

Comment: I really don't see the need for sarcasm. You assign `audioInput` yet never check `error2`. Given that `audioInput` is where you're having a problem isn't that a reasonable suggestion?

Comment: No error messages ever show. However, I found a common denominator. Audio will record, but only if recording is 10 seconds or shorter. If it hits 11 seconds the audio doesn't record.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is `movieFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid;`  Apparently it is set to 10 default, and anything after, audio won't record.  Referenced from [AVCaptureSession audio doesn't work for long videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768987/avcapturesession-audio-doesnt-work-for-long-videos)

Was easy to find answer once I figured out time was involved with the problem

Comment: thanks for the answer. but this does not make any sense.

Comment: wow apple seriously? OMG I was like why am getting only 10 seconds audio

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2

```
movieFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = CMTime.invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
videoFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
```

solved this for me.

However, I accidentally set the movieFragmentInterval after calling startRecordingToOutputFileURL. An agonising hour later I realised my mistake. For newbies like me - note THIS OBVIOUS SEQUENCE.

```
videoFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
videoFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
```

Comment: what is it do? Can you explain