# Recording video with front camera via AVCaptureSession return with NO Audio

Tags: ios, audio, avcapturesession

I'm trying to record a video via `AVCapturesession`but the problem is the video contain no sound Although I add an AudioInputDevice

```
[_session stopRunning];
[_session beginConfiguration];
NSError *error;
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];

NSLog(@"Error %@",error);

        if ([_session canAddInput:audioInput])
        {
            [_session addInput:audioInput];
        }

        [_session commitConfiguration];
        [_session startRunning];
```

No error and no audio if it's the front camera and normal video with audio if it's the back camera

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032130/audio-not-recording-in-avcapturesession)?

Comment: yes I did but this is not my case the back camera record with Audio !!